# Postgresql json select from values in second layer of containment of arrays

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I have a jsonb column 'data' that contains a tree like json, example:

```
{
    "libraries":[
        {    
            "books":[
                {
                    "name":"mybook",
                    "type":"fiction"
                },
                {
                    "name":"yourbook",
                    "type":"comedy"
                }
                {
                    "name":"hisbook",
                    "type":"fiction"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to do a index using query that selects a value from the indented "book" jsons according to the type.
so all book names that are fiction.

I was able to do this using jsonb_array_elements a join query, but as i understand this would not be optimized with using the GIN index.
my query is

```
select books->'name'
from data,
     jsonb_array_elements(data->'libraries') libraries,
     jsonb_array_elements(libraries->'books') books,
where books->>'type'='grading'
```

Comment: There's work on a general json path query search, but AFAIK nothing yet in 9.4 or 9.5 beyond `json_extract_path`, which doesn't handle wildcard entries, pattern matches ,etc.

Comment: @Berethor Just wondering if you ever figured out a work around for this.

Answer (score -1):

If the example data you are showing is the type of data that is common in your JSON, I would suggest that you may be setting things up wrong.

Why not make a library table and a book table and not use JSON at all, it seems JSON is not the right choice here.

```
CREATE TABLE library
(
   id serial, 
   name text
);

CREATE TABLE book
(
   isbn BIGINT,
   name text,
   book_type text
);

CREATE TABLE library_books
(
   library_id integer,
   isbn BIGINT
)

select book.* from library_books where library_id = 1;
```

Comment: The example above is just what it is, an example. in reality the json was chosen because the data here is very dynamic, and does not only include books or libraries (which are also surrogates i used to simplify the example)